# Regex pattern to valid file name

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of filenames which will have name like this :

```
ADB_FULL_REQ_XXXXXXXXXXXX_151004_01.dat
```

Where :

`ADB_FULL_REQ_` is constant

`XXXXXXXXXXXX` is the computer's Mac Address

`151004` represents the date in `yyMMdd` format

`01` is 2 digits and maximum is **99**

I will have to perform a search in the diretory which contains those files and check if any of them is invalid/valid.

I've tried to use RegEX with this pattern but Match.Success always return false :

```
Match match = Regex.Match(filename, @"^ADB_FULL_REQ_XXXXXXXXXXXX_(d\{6})_(d\{2}).dat")
```

Please show me what'm I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: You have to take care of Mac Address too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is not big:

```
^ADB_FULL_REQ_[a-fA-F0-9]{12}_(\d{6})_(\d{2}).dat
```

you used `d\` instead of `\d`. Change it and this will work fine (I've added checking for MAC address).

Comment: @NguyenHoang glad to help :)

Comment: Could you explain to me the part `[a-fA-F0-9]` ?

Comment: I understand now, just got a little confused!

Comment: @NguyenHoang yeah, it's for case insensitivity :)

Answer (score 2):

You missed to check the MAC address:

```
^ADB_FULL_REQ_[\dA-F]{12}_(\d{6})_(\d{2}).dat$
```